# Don't understand the approach to get answer to simple Combinatorics question.

Tags: combinatorics

"What is the number of chess pairings you can make with 10 people on three chess boards. It should not count as a different pairing if two people at the same board switch places and it shouldn’t matter which pair sits at which board.”

The answer on my notes is 9×7×5×3×1 = 945.

I do not understand why its 9 x 7 x 5 x 1. Why do you multiply 9 by 7 then by 5 then by 3 then by 1? I cannot come up with a logical explanation for it.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Arrange all ten in a row.

The leftmost person in the row has $9$ choices for partner.
The leftmost person now left unpaired has $7$ choices for partner, and so on.

---

$\underline{Re\; your\; comment\; and\; revision\; to\; question}$

3 may be a typo for 5 boards. If there are only 3 boards, with only 3 pairs to be formed, then the given answer is incorrect, You would first need to choose the 6 people who will play, and you can then form pairs, thus $\binom{10}6⋅5⋅3⋅1$

Comment: Apologies, I left out in my question there are only 3 boards.

Answer (score 0):

You may calculate in this way:

> $$ \frac{10!}{5!2^5}$$

The way to explain to is as follow:

1) Put ten person in a row: you have 10! possibilities to do this

2) You have divide by 5! to take into account the repetition of this kind

$$|AB|CD|EF|GH|IL \equiv |CD|AB|EF|GH|IL$$

3) You also have to divide by $2^5$ to take into account the repetition of this kind

$$|AB|CD|EF|GH|IL \equiv |BA|CD|EF|GH|IL$$

With **only three boards** you can choose 6 people between 10 in ${10}\choose{6}$ different ways and then for each case calculate as before.Thus we have:

$$ {10\choose6} \frac{6!}{3!2^3}$$

Comment: Apologies I left out in the question that there are only 3 boards.

Comment: No matter I've update my answer, but now it's different from the solution you have!